# Postgresql not using my index

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing

I can't understand why my query is doing a sequential scan.

```
select columns
from table
where (column_1 ilike '%whatever%' or column_2 ilike '%whatever%')
```

I have an index on both column_1 and column_2.

The cardinality on both columns is very high.

My table is roughly 25 million rows.

What do you think I might be doing wrong?  No matter what I do, it always does a sequential scan.

Edit #1:
My index looks like this:

```
Create index xxx on table  (column_1, column_2);
```

Edit #2:
Changing my sql query to

```
select columns
from table
where (column_1 ilike 'whatever%' and column_2 ilike 'whatever%')
```

still made my query use a sequential scan. I got the same result when I just used `like` instead of `ilike`. But this query:

```
select columns
from table
where (column_1 = 'whatever' and column_2 = whatever)
```

made my query use an index scan and my query went much faster :)

Comment: See here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/144899/1822

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two Reasons:

- Your query does a `OR` condition in which index can't be used.
- You are doing a ilike on **"%xyz%"**. This can't use any help of sorted(i.e. indexed) data.

--

Edit: See if you can have `like` on "xyz%". Then index can be used if you do a separate condition on both columns (and separate index on both)

Edit2: By the query, the thing you are trying to do looks like Full Text Search. For that you would need search indexing techniques (Read Elasticsearch, Sphinx, Solr)

Comment: Can you edit your post and be more specific when you say do a separate condition on both columns?

Comment: Can you modify your where condition to do a 'like' condition as I mentioned above..

Comment: A trigram index can speed up `ilike '%xyz%'`: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/144899/1822